# CS50 Credit: Input were asked 3 times not sure how to fix it

Tags: c, cs50

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I have figured out the correct algorithm and written it in code. But whenever I ran the program, it asks for user input multiple times.

I am sure it has something to do with the way I set up my functions. But I'm not sure exactly how I could best approach it.

Thank you guys in advance for guiding me.

Here's the code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//initialization
long get_credit(void); // obtain numbers from the user
int get_digit(void); //calculate the number of digits

//Declaring variables
int sum, sum1, tot1, length, i, tot2, total, total2, total3, sum2;

int main(void)
{
    long credit = get_credit();
    length = get_digit();
    printf("Card Length: %i\n",length);

    //use if and else statement to validate the card length
        if (length >= 13 && length <= 16)
        {
//When card length condition is satisfied, use check sum condition.
//Check Sum: Using int division to eliminate digits then use modulo to find the number. Loop this by
// The sum of the digits starting from second to last.
            for (i = 0; i <= length/2 ; i++)
            {
                long num1 = credit / 10;
                long num2 = num1 % 10;
                // printf("Credit: %li\n",num2);
                sum = num2*2;
                    if (sum >= 10)
                    {
                        sum1 = sum/10;
                        sum = sum % 10;
                        tot2 = tot2 + sum1 + sum;
                        // printf("Sum1:%i\n",sum1);
                        // printf("Sum: %i\n",sum);
                        // printf("tot2: %i\n",tot2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tot1 += sum;
                        // printf("Sum: %i\n",sum);
                        // printf("tot1: %i\n",tot1);
                    }
                credit = num1 / 10; // Loop by changing by setting the value to be one less digit
            }
            total = total + tot1 + tot2;
            // printf("TOTAL: %i\n",total);

//Check sum for the digits starting from the last digit

            credit = get_credit();
            for (i = 0; i <= length/2 ; i++)
            {
                long num3 = credit % 10;
                // printf("Credit: %li\n",num3);
                credit = credit / 100;
                total2 += num3;
            }
            // printf("Total 2: %i\n",total2);

            if(total3 % 10 == 0)
            {
            // // Using nested if loops to check the conditions
                if (length == 15) //American Express
                {
                    credit = credit / 10000000000000; // eliminate 13 digits in the beginning
                        if (credit % 10 == 4 || credit % 10 == 7)
                        {
                            credit = credit / 10;
                                if (credit % 10 == 3)
                                {
                                    printf("AMEX");
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("INVALID1\n");
                        }
                }

                if (length == 16) //Master Card
                {
                    credit = credit / 100000000000000; // eliminate 14 digits in the beginning
                        if (credit % 10 == 1 || credit % 10 == 2 || credit % 10 == 3 || credit % 10 == 4 || credit % 10 == 5)
                        {
                            credit = credit / 10;
                                if (credit % 10 == 5)
                                {
                                    printf("MASTERCARD");
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("INVALID2\n");
                        }
                }

                if (length == 13) //VISA
                {
                    credit = credit / 1000000000000; // eliminate 12 digits in the beginning
                        if (credit % 10 == 4)
                        {
                            printf("VISA");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("INVALID3\n");
                        }
                }

                if (length == 16) //VISA
                {
                    credit = credit / 1000000000000000; // eliminate 15 digits in the beginning
                        if (credit % 10 == 4)
                        {
                            printf("VISA");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("INVALID4\n");
                        }
                }
            }

            else
            {
            printf("INVALID5\n");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID!\n");
        }
}


//prompt user to enter the credit card number and print it on screen
 long get_credit()
 {
     long credit_number = get_long("Number: ");
    //printf("Number: %li\n",credit_number); //debugging
   return credit_number;
}

//digits lengther
int get_digit()
{
        long credit = get_credit(); //lengthing the number of digits given by the user
        length = 0;
        while(credit != 0)
        {
        credit = credit/10 ;
        length ++ ;
        }
        return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_credit()` prints string `"Number: "` and read user input. This happens each time the function `get_credit()` is called.

1. In `main()` you call `get_credit` at first line
2. Then you call the function `get_digit`, which calls `get_credit` again
3. Then `get_credit` is called again before loop `for (i = 0; i <= length/2 ; i++)`

So you can expect `"Number: "` is properly printed three times when you run this code.

If your aim is to ask only once user input, just call `get_credit` once then store returning value in a variable. Then use the variable instead calling again the function. You can pass this variable to the function `get_digit` as argument.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I figured something was wrong with the way I'm calling my function. But I'm still a little confused on how I could store the returning value in a variable since I have assigned the variable "credit number" as the stored variable. However, I can't use that variable in the get_digit function ...